# precision and recall for biased data

Tags: probability, classification, mathematical-statistics, precision-recall

here is my assumption input data's labels are 99% true and there are only 1% false(trying to say most of the data are true).
My classifier's probability is 0.5. just like unbiased coin flip.
in this situation shouldn't precision be almost 1 and recall be 1/2?
because when i assume there are 10 data and 9 data are labeled true ,1 data is false. then TP is 4.5 , FP is almost 0.5 and FN is 4.5 am i right? but standford lecture says recall shoud be 1/2 and precision should be very low. 
https://youtu.be/pO3Jsr31s_Q?t=4442[image]

Comment: In order to do assumptions about precision and recall is necessary to know the classifier's prediction. What do you mean: `My classifier's probability is 0.5. just like an unbiased coin flip.`?

Comment: @fmassica I think the OP should clarify it as "random classifier with probability 0.5 of saying true", because the lecture quoted is using it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct after your initial assumption. When the classifier is random, for any given sample it'll correctly guess the class with 0.5 probability. This can be seemed as guessing 0.5 samples out of 1 sample. Just to reiterate your logic, if 9 out of 10 were positive, we'd correctly guess 4.5 of them, which is counted as true positive. And, out of 10 samples, we guess 5 as positive, yielding a high precision: $0.9$.

However, the problem in the online lecture deals 16 different binary classification problems each with low positive ratios, which result in low precision values.

Comment: i thought i understand what you said ...
i am not sure what is ' 16 different binary classification '  can you tell me any key word to study?

Comment: Since there are 16 different classes in the problem, they employ one vs all strategy for each class. Therefore, 16 different precision/recall values are produced and the final value reported is just their average.

Comment: oh most of data are labels are not true i thought opposite way. the true ratio has to be low since one example can have 16 classes but there is only one match so it is 1/16 right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: thank you so much have a nice day!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i checked the 'check sign' to green and clicked upper triangle

Comment: @임도현 Thank you!